# mongoid model and warning validation messages

Tags: ruby, validation, warnings, mongoid

I would like to implement warning errors on model validation with Ruby mongoid gem.

I kinda followed this example found here [Efficient way to report record validation warnings as well as errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24628628/efficient-way-to-report-record-validation-warnings-as-well-as-errors)

```rb
class MyModel

validate :check_warnings

def warnings
  @warnings ||= ActiveModel::Errors.new(self)
end

def check_warnings
  warnings.add(:some_field, :not_exist) if some_field.blank?
  warnings.add(:another_field, :not_exist) if another_field.blank?
end
end
```

When warnings value is acessed in Rails helper to display warnings, it is empty.

```rb
p doc.warnings.size => 0
```

But if I force a validation error

```rb
def check_warnings
  warnings.add(:some_field, :not_exist) if some_field.blank?
  warnings.add(:another_field, :not_exist) if another_field.blank?

  errors.add(:yet_another_field, :not_exist) if yet_another_field.blank?
end

# in helper
p doc.errors.size => 1
p doc.warnings.size => 2
```

warning errors are preserved.

Is this maybe a mongoid bug or am I missing something.

by
TheR

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform the validation (by calling `validate`, `valid?`, `save`/`save!` etc.) before looking at the errors or your warnings. If you simply look at errors or warnings without having validated you will have empty sets.